# with ARC: how to implement a custom atomic property?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, atomic, synthesize

In **ARC**, I want an atomic property for multi-thread access:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (atomic, strong) NSString *myString;
@end
```

I also want a custom setter and getter for various reasons, like debugging or tracking.

Solution A, I override the setter and getter:

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myString = _myString;
static int i;
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)myString
{
    _myString = myString;
    NSLog(@"%d", i++);
}
- (NSString *)myString
{
    return _myString;
}
@end
```

Solution B, I extend the class interface to have a different synthesized property:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (atomic, strong) NSString *myPrivateString;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myPrivateString = _myPrivateString;
static int i;
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)myString
{
    _myPrivateString = myString;
    NSLog(@"%d", i++);
}
- (NSString *)myString
{
    return _myPrivateString;
}
@end
```

Is solution A atomic? Is solution B atomic? If none of them are atomic, should I use [objc_setProperty and objc_getProperty](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html), or should I use @synchronized(self), or is there a better locking mechanism to avoid locking self?

(sub-question: in case B, getting or setting `_myPrivateString` directly is as safe as getting or setting `self.myPrivateString` or not as safe?)

Comment: Read the hundreds of questions about atomic properties. You will find that you are completely missing the point and that atomic properties will very rarely do anything good for you. And instance variables without leading underscore are a _very_ bad habit that makes your code unreadable.

Comment: Adding the underscore does not change the question at all. As for "completely missing the point", try to state why "atomic" is the default value and for which case it is good.

Answer (score 1):

> Is solution A atomic?

No, it's not.  As you are providing a custom version of the getter/setter methods, you'll also need to provide the locking mechanism.  Using `@synchronized(self)` will work, however if there is high contention for this property, you might want to create a locking object for each property.  That's unlikely, however.

> Is solution B atomic?

Yes it is, however be sure to use `self.myPrivateString = myString;` to ensure you access the getter/setter methods, where the locking is implemented.

I would recommend using solution A as it's simple, which is always good.

Comment: I think solution B (with the correction you mentioned) would be more suitable than introducing my own locking mechanism.

Comment: @Cœur Well it depends what debugging/tracking you are doing in the getter/setter; it's possible they need exclusive access themselves...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an instance variable without a leading underscore, you have fallen into the trap of actually accessing the instance variable instead of the accessor method. When you access the instance variable, "atomic" won't do _anything" for you. Anyone with any Objective-C experience will advice you very, very strongly not to use instance variables without the leading underscore. Just remove the @synthesize (so you built yourself a trap, fell into it, and you actually did extra work to do so).

So none of your solutions is in any way atomic.